# How can i download data from a specific URL using beautifoulsoup and saving the result as an excel file?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to download the Net Income of the s&p 500 companies from this website https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/MMM/3m/income-statement

I wrote this part of code following an online guide (this one https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-for-accounting-analysis-using-python-part-1-b5fc016a1c9a), but i can't figure out how to conlude it and, more specifically, how to download the extracted Net Income into an excel file.

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/MMM/3m/income-statement'
response = requests.get(url)

response
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

income_statement = soup.findAll('a')[19]
link = income_statement['href']
download_url = 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/MMM/3m/income-statement/'+ link
```

Any suggestion would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct way to tackle this mission is to use some stock market API instead of web scraping with BS4.
I'll recommend you to have a look at the following article, it also includes some practical examples:
https://towardsdatascience.com/best-5-free-stock-market-apis-in-2019-ad91dddec984

**Edit:**

If you decide to stick to the plan of using this exact URL you mentioned, I think you should try to use `pandas`, try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_html('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/MMM/3m/income-statement​',skiprows=1)
```

You'll have to play with encoding a little bit as the table contains some non-ascii chars

Comment: Great thanks for the quick answer, i was thinking earlier to an APi, dunno why didn't try it earlier. Anyway, do you think they also have data about the company (rather than information of the stocks such as price, high, low etc etc)?

Comment: I just edited my comment, `pandas` is able to do it for you, however, in this specific URL some encoding adjustments are required.
But I think you should stick to using API, I don't familiar with them some I can't guide you to a specific one but I can assure that it is undoubtedly the right way to do it.
Have some research, find an API that fits your needs :)